# Flutter Firestore - type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm doing a pagination query on a firestore collection. The query below works fine without the `.startAfter(lastVisible)` on the first query, but when we get to the second query shown below it crashes when building the query with the error:

> Unhandled Exception: type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

When I look at the quick access on the IDE it tells me that `Query startAfter(List<dynamic>)` looks for a parameter of List<dynamic>, but the official API says to pass startAfter() a DocumentSnapshot of the item you want to start after, which is what I (think) am setting lastVisible to in the last line of my code provided below.
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#startAfter(com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot)

if I try to declare it in a list, `.startAfter([lastVisible])` I get: `Invalid argument: Instance of 'QueryDocumentSnapshot` which points to the line at `.get()`

Any help is appreciated.

```dart
response = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('referrals')
  .where("toUID", isEqualTo: memberID)
  .orderBy('dateTime', descending: true)
  .limit(ReferralListController.PAGE_SIZE)
  .startAfter(lastVisible) // < ---------  crashes here??
  .get();

lastVisible = response.docs[response.docs.length - 1]; // < --  where I set lastVisible  ??
```

Comment: what's the datatype of `response`?

Comment: response is a querysnapshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Query.startAfter()` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/startAfter.html) takes a list of the document's values as its arguments. You're looking for [`Query.startAfterDocument`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/startAfterDocument.html).

Comment: When looking at the API, I don't see a query.startafterdocument(). I believe that's a depreciated use of startafter(). If I'm wrong, can you point it out?

Comment: The method names in my answer link to the current documentation for both `Query.startAfter()` and `Query.startAfterDocument()`. If you're using an older version of the libraries the signatures could be different, but from the error message you get, it is clear that `startAfter` does not accept a `DocumentSnapshot`.

Comment: Gotcha. I was looking at the wrong API docs. Firestore's official docs don't have flutter, but the version I was looking at I couldn't find a startafterdocument.